How to add new collator to a running parachain at runtime?
I have a parachain with kusama as relay chain and it is live. I am looking for the right set of steps to add new collators to the running chain in runtime. The initial chainspec does not have any info of new collators.The new collators are completely new . Can anyone help please?

Yes, these guides may be helpful:

https://hackmd.io/@s_iGZLIITG6WjSgnFX0pcg/the-collator-setup-guide
https://docs.oak.tech/docs/setup-collator-node

